# Detecting first member of POD types for SFINAE

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, c++17, sfinae, type-traits

Given some POD structs similar to this:

```
struct StandardHeader
{
    uint32_t field1;
    uint32_t field2;
};

struct TypeA
{
    StandardHeader Header;
    uint8_t field3;
};

struct TypeB
{
    StandardHeader Header;
    uint16_t field4;
};
```

I would like to write a type trait (or something similar that can eventually be used in a `static_assert` and `std::enable_if` or otherwise disable a templated method) which can detect the existence of the `StandardHeader` field as the first member of a standard layout type -- ie. such that `reinterpret_cast<StandardHeader*>(&instance)` is safe.

(Essentially, an *is-a* base type check, except that the types do have to be PODs, which won't be true if I use actual C++ inheritance.)

I was able to write something that used the detection idiom to verify that the type is standard layout and has a `Header` member of the correct type:

```
template<typename, typename = std::void_t<>>
struct HasStandardHeader : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct HasStandardHeader<T,
        std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().Header)>>
    : std::conditional_t<
        std::is_standard_layout_v<T> &&
        std::is_same_v<decltype(std::declval<T>().Header), StandardHeader>
    , std::true_type, std::false_type> {};
```

The above partly works, but doesn't verify that the field was the first one.

I tried to add something along the lines of this expression to detect that, but it doesn't work:

```
static_cast<uint8_t*>(&static_cast<T*>(0)->Header) - static_cast<uint8_t*>(0)) == 0
```

(Other failed attempts involved calling a `constexpr bool` method, but sadly those don't appear to be valid in `conditional_t`.  Or at least not when using `&` or something.)

Ideally I'd prefer something that just detects the field with the correct type is there, without even requiring that it be named `Header`.  Is that possible?  And is there a better way of rewriting the above?

As mentioned before, the end goal is to make this method:

```
template<typename T>
bool Process(T& data, size_t len);
```

either disappear or `static_assert` if `T` isn't a POD type with the correct first member.

---

**Edit**: looks like I might have been overcomplicating it a little.  Adding this expression makes it work as expected:

```
offsetof(T, Header) == 0
```

But now:

- Is there a better way to write this whole thing?
- Is it possible to write this such that we don't require the field to be called `Header`?

Answer (score 4):

Just check offsetof of the member.

```
template<typename, typename = std::void_t<>>
struct HasStandardHeader : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct HasStandardHeader<T,
        std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().Header)>>
    : std::conditional_t<
        std::is_standard_layout<T>::value &&
        std::is_same<decltype(std::declval<T>().Header), StandardHeader>::value &&
        offsetof(T, Header) == 0
    , std::true_type, std::false_type> {};
```

Tested a little on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/VKePV9).

Comment: Heh, looks like we both thought of that at the same time. :)

Comment: This is not an answer to my whole question.  It was an answer to the original question, which I had already updated with similar code and followup questions before this was posted.